# Using Composer to Manage Site-Level Dependencies

Tags: config

I would like to use Composer to manage dependencies for my site, like Twitter's Bootstrap.

Is there a recommended way to integrate Composer with Craft to support managing this type of Global dependency (as opposed to managing dependencies for an individual plugin)?

Or should I make a plugin that somehow sets up Bootstrap as the theme for my site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you really want is something like Bower:

http://bower.io

It has Bootstrap in its manifest, amongst many others.